# Jquery - convert object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function create_image(){
        <?php if(isset($avatar)) : ?>
            var brojac = 4;
        <?php else: ?>
            var brojac = 5;
        <?php endif; ?>
        var broj_slike = (5 - brojac) + 1,
        slike;
        for (var i = 0; i <= brojac; i++) {
            slike += $('<label for="image'+ broj_slike +'">Slika ' + broj_slike + '</label><input type="file" name="userfile" id="image' + broj_slike + '" />');
            broj_slike++;
        };
        return slike;
     }
```

It is returning this:

**undefined[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]**

How can I covert this into string?

Comment: It actually is a string (that's what you see). What's the generated output by PHP (so the plain JS, not with the <?php stuff)? Do you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: I think that stuff generated PHP is not important for returning string. Anyway, getting rid of $ seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with a string of HTML … don't convert each string to a jQuery object.

Get rid of `$(` and `)`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create jQuery object?

```
var broj_slike = (5 - brojac) + 1,
    slike = "";   // don't forget to init the string

for (var i = 0; i <= brojac; i++) {
    slike += '<label for="image'+ broj_slike +'">Slika ' + broj_slike + '</label> \
              <input type="file" name="userfile" id="image' + broj_slike + '" />';

    broj_slike++;
};
```

Comment: I really don't know :D. When I loose $ it is working. Thank you for the help :)